# SQL creating new database from dirty data-set

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database, bash

I have a bit of a conundrum:  I am developing a relational database of manufacturers and models of medical devices for internal use.  The source of this data (a dump from the FDA) is very dirty, and provided in a CSV, so it is imported into a single table with no relevant keys to start with.
Meanwhile, I am looking to move the imported data into

1. table of manufacturers
2. table of models (relative to manufacturers)

... to be used by my application

While it is easy to match exact manufacturer and model names, or strings of manufacturer and model names stripped of special characters via unique indexing, the problem seems to be that there are many cases when there are suffixes and variations to the names, such as:

- ST JUDES
- ST JUDES, INC
- ST JUDES - NEURO
- ST JUDES INC CARDIO
- SAINT JUDES INTERNATIONAL

Ideally, all of these should be 1 manufacturer record, once moved from the CSV import table to the table structure I'm developing for internal use.

Three will also be a weekly batch job downloading a new CSV, importing to the CSV's table, and updating the internal table structure.

My initial thoughts were to use  unique index of soundex values or clean strings, but neither of those will work given the examples above.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?  I am familiar with Bash, SQL, PHP, and a bit of Python. This is a very small snippet of the dirty CSV.  With all CSVs, it is about 30M records
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/MAUDE/ftparea/foidev2013.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/), which is designed to do this kind of data normalization / cleansing. The videos on the homepage do a good job of introducing its features.

The last time I used it it wasn't fully batch-able, but it was possible to serialize your normalization rules into a JSON string and use that string to reapply the same actions on a new data set.

Comment: This is an awesome tool, thanks!  This will defiantly help me overcome my initial hurdles.  Do you have a suggested method for handling a batch import of equally as dirty data, just not as big?

Comment: @c-griffin, I still think this is your best bet even for a small data set. Play with the JSON serialization for repeated imports. Good luck!